# How does the Community user have 3 reputation here on Meta?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, meta, community-user

On most sites (including on main), the Community user's reputation is stuck at 1. However, if you look at the very instant that this question was posted, the [Community user](https://meta.superuser.com/users/-1/community)'s reputation here is 3. I am curious about two things:

- Why is the Community user's reputation something different from 1?
- Why does it have a reputation different from that on the main site?

**UPDATE:** Three weeks after asking this question, the Community user's reputation is still 3. Which means that, its rep is not syncing for whatever reason.

Comment: Obviously, it asked a question on SuperUser and received one upvote, before superuser's meta-thing was migrated to meta.superuser. (I'm taking a wild guess here; this is *probably wrong*, but it sounded funny)

Comment: @allquixotic If it asked a question on main and received an upvote, it would have **6** reputation, not 3.

Comment: Suggested edits by anonymous users are attributed to Community. IIRC if one is accepted, Community gets the rep, and it's periodically reset. Not sure though.

Comment: Weird since there's no suggested edits on meta though (cc @DanielBeck)

Comment: See: [Eeeek! "Community" user got sudden rep boost.. how come?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77115)

Comment: @nhinkle Maybe it's main site rep that hasn't been synched yet?

Comment: I'm going to check on this just to make sure it's not a regression - I see no events that could have given it rep.

Comment: @TimPost What was the result?

Comment: @gparyani Will let you know as soon as I can get a dev to take a peek. I'm kind of scratching my head on what it ended up owning that resulted in it.

Comment: Community now has a rep of 1, so this question is now obsolete.